kubernetes job gets triggered always
I have kubernetes deployment with init container which triggers a job through configmap mounted to it. However I have added a condition to start the init container.
initContainers:
{{ if .Values.global.test.enabled }}
- name: wait-db
  image: "x"
  command:
  - /bin/sh
  - -c
  - /test.sh -n test -p /test.yaml
  volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /test.yaml
      name: test-configmap
      subPath: test.yaml
{{ else }}
- name: wait-db-x
  image: "x"
  command:
  - /bin/sh
  - -c
  - /test.sh -n test-x -p /testx.yaml
  volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /testx.yaml
      name: testx-configmap
      subPath: testx.yaml
{{ end }}


I see that when I set global.test.enabled to true in values file, it also triggers test-x job though the init container wait-db-x is not executed. When I describe the deployment, I see only one init container exists wait-db. What am I missing?
Also, I see that this is not the issue on new install, this happens only during helm upgrade
Tried deleting the jobs before upgrade

Also, I updated the job in configmap, does this trigger the job irrespective of init containers existence?

A Job is a specific Kubernetes object with a specific lifecycle.  Is a Job actually involved here?  Can you clarify what specific behavior you're seeing; it sounds like you set the enabled flag to true, run helm upgrade, but see the else init container run when the Deployment is updated?

If you only have the problem when upgrading, it could be due to caching or default values. If you have performed multiple deployments or updates without performing a proper helm upgrade --install, there may be values stored in the previous release. In this case, you can try forcing an upgrade with the --reset-values flag to ensure that the new values are applied correctly:
helm upgrade --install <release_name> <chart_name> --reset-values

